# Separating Differences of Open Sets

Tags: gn.general-topology, separation-axioms

Has anyone ever considered something like the following separation axiom?

$(*)$ For any pair of open sets $O$ and $N$, there exist disjoint open sets containing $O\setminus N$ and $N\setminus O$.

Any $T_1$ space that is not Hausdorff will fail $(*)$ but I would be interested to know of any Hausdorff spaces failing $(*)$.  Such a space could not be too nice, as any perfectly normal (e.g. metric) space $X$ satisfies $(*)$.  To see this, take continuous $f,g:X\rightarrow\mathbb{R}_+$ with $f^{-1}\{0\}=X\setminus O$ and $g^{-1}\{0\}=X\setminus N$ and consider the disjoint open sets on which $f-g$ is positive and negative.  Can perfect normality be weakened here?  Is $(*)$ perhaps equivalent to some classical topological conditions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note that condition $(*)$ is equivalent to "every open subspace is normal" and it is a standard exercise to show that spaces with this property are exactly the completely normal ($T_5$) spaces.

Comment: Can you elaborate on the equivalence? I was just finishing an answer about $(*)$ implying that the space is hereditarily normal, but I can't see the other direction.

Comment: @Joonas: $O \setminus N$ and $N \setminus O$ are disjoint closed subsets of $O \cup N$.

Comment: Great, thanks, I see it too now, at least the first part (I'll have to think about the standard exercise a bit).